# Imprecise descriptions of bugs/exceptions when debugging EJS templates

Tags: ejs, node-debugger

EJS documentation at [ejs.co](https://ejs.co) says "*It's easy to debug EJS errors: your errors are plain JavaScript exceptions, with template line-numbers included.*".

However, when debugging the code with an bug in the template, I only get references to the functions inside my *cza.js* module that calls the `ejs.renderFile` and references to the "internal" errors within the EJS (*ejs.js*) itself. Reference to the bug within the *.ejs* template (ideally the line-number) is missing, in fact the template goes unmentioned.

So, the screenshot is of an the error within *ejs.js*, where EJS itself got stuck processing the bugged template, NOT the template itself, and so worthless:
[image]

So, how do I get the debugger to point out the bug in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have just found out that EJS **does** print out the code to terminal, unless a debugger does not step in to handle the exception before EJS can point out the bug. 
In my scenario, I debug the app using `node --inspect app.js`, with debug auto-attach in VS Code enabled. The debugger then describes the exception as shown in the question screenshot.

How I found out the debugger was blocking EJS's output to terminal? I had a browser already requesting the app, when I launched it and the exception occured within the second before the debugger was attached.